# Compare "Whenever I see Graham, he's wearing/wears a tracksuit." in meaning

Tags: present-tense, present-continuous, present-simple

Is there any difference between these sentences?

> Whenever I see Graham, he's wearing a tracksuit.
>
> Whenever I see Graham, he wears a tracksuit.

Also somewhat similar:

> I like to listen to music when I drive
>
> I like to listen to music when I'm driving

I was reading John Eastwood's "Oxford guide to English grammar". From page 82 he starts explaining the difference between the present simple and present continuous tenses and gives some examples but I was wondering whether in these examples the second variant of tense is possible and what it can possibly mean if it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Whenever I see Graham he's wearing a track suit.

On those occasions when I happen to meet Graham by chance, he's always wearing a track suit. (A possible implication: You might  think a track suit was the only piece of clothing he owns, or these are uncanny coincidences.)

> Whenever I see Graham, he wears a tracksuit.

On those occasions when Graham and I have arranged to meet, he wears a track suit.  (For example: We go running on those occasions.)

The simple present (he wears) implies a habit or practice, and so we interpret the subordinate clause as referring to a regular, prearranged meeting.

The present continuous (is wearing) implies not  a regular practice but a discrete action-in-progress, and so we interpret the subordinate clause as referring to something other than an arranged or habitual meeting,  namely,  a chance encounter.

Comment: +1 for the explanation as it applies to the first contrast, but how about the second? It seems unlikely that we'd choose *drive* vs *driving* there based on "whether we happened to be driving" or made an arrangement to do so.

Comment: Also, on thinking about it more, I think that *Whenever I see Graham, he wears . . ..* is relatively unlikely. More commonly, I suspect we'd use another verb that makes it clearer something was arranged, and I think we would much more commonly include an *always* (even though it's not necessary and arguably redundant given the *whenever.*

Comment: @Jim Reynolds: I agree that a more careful statement would probably express the subordinate clause more clearly (Whenever I **happen to run into** Graham, he's wearing a tracksuit.).  But such carefulness is not obligatory for the grammar, and we do use the main clause to understand the meaning of the subordinate clause in such circumstances.

Comment: @JimReynolds I could imagine choosing **drive** if I'm trying to identify the times when I choose to drive instead of being a passenger. For example: "I carpool to work with Bob every day and we take turns driving.  I like to listen to music when I drive, but he finds it distracting when he drives."

Comment: @Can Yes. Interesting. We would probably stress *I* if speaking the sentence, another indicator that we are contrasting *I* with *Bob* in your example. It seems to me that we'd alternatively use *I'm driving* and *he's driving* in that example, and the two choices could mean the same things sometimes, and at other times, the present simple would indicate a habit (general truth type use) while the -ing form would emphasize immediacy/short-term. Something like that. :)

Answer (score 0):

The first sentences are a bit distorted for clear comprehension. A suggestion: you may put it this way 'Graham, likes wearing a tracksuit', or 'most at times, i see Graham wearing a tracksuit'. For your second question, you may use either of the two; it's normal.

Comment: Neither of those means the same thing as the original two sentences, though.